# How to switch the base language for my .ts files

Tags: qt, translation, qt-linguist

Now, suddenly after a few years, I'm going to replace all German strings with English ones in my C++ sources. The question is how to turn my already existing German-to-targetLanguage .ts files into English-to-targetLanguage .ts files.

I've got the en_US.ts file which translates from German to English. For example, is there a tool that can turn my old fr_FR.ts file (based on German source strings) into a new one (based on English source strings) with the help of that en_US.ts?

Comment: Wouldn't `fr_FR.ts` be for French?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow along with what you want to do... Do you want to (automatically?) translate your German texts into English, and then the English into French? Why the immediate step of English? Why not directly from German to French?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I guess that the main issue is making the source code more international by using english strings in the code and avoiding to replace each german line in fr_FR.ts with the new english string.  [This qt link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlinguist-hellotr-example.html) mentions `linguist` and `lupdate` although I'm not sure this is what the OP is looking for

Comment: @stefaanv: I already use the linguist and lupdate stuff for my current German-based translation machinery

Comment: I guessed so, but it wasn't obvious.  Sorry, I can't help you with this.  I was thinking in line of making a python script for this, but an already made tool would probably be nice.

Comment: yes, a python script sounds nice. I would even set a good bounty for such answer (although I'm not sure if it's allowed by the SO policy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had been quite easy to modify/extend the lupdate tool doing exactly that. Done.